# string conversion error in array codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my controller I have a error on this line `'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group_controller_update') .'/'. $this->getId($controller)`

**When I refresh my page it throws the error Array to string conversion**

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string
>   conversion Filename: user/users_group_update.php Line Number: 47

Not sure what to do on that because I need to add variable **$controller** in to `$this->getId($controller);`

**What changes is best suited to make this work.**

```
<?php

class Users_group_update extends Admin_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');
}

public function index() {

    $data['title'] = "Users Group Update";

    $controller_files = $this->getInstalled($this->uri->segment(3)); 

    $data['controller_files'] = array();

    $files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

    if ($files) {

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $controller =  basename(strtolower($file), '.php');

            $do_not_list = array(
                'customer_total',
                'dashboard',
                'footer',
                'header',
                'login',
                'logout',
                'menu',
                'online',
                'permission',
                'register',
                'user_total'
            ); 

            if (!in_array($controller, $do_not_list)) {

                $data['controller_files'][] = array(
                    'name' => $controller,
                    'installed' => in_array($controller, $controller_files),
                    'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group_controller_update') .'/'. $this->getId($controller)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_form_update', $data);
}

public function getInstalled($name) {
    $controller_data = array();

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {
        $controller_data[] = $result['controller'];
    }

    return $controller_data;
}

public function getId($controller) {
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
    $this->db->where('name', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->where('controller', $controller);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row('user_group_id');
}
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');?>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/menu/index');?>
<div id="page-wrapper" >
<div id="page-inner">

<?php 

$data = array(
'class' => 
'form-horizontal', 
'id' => 
'form-users-group'
);
echo form_open_multipart('admin/users_group_update' .'/'. $this->uri->segment(3), $data);?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px"><h1 class="panel-title"><?php echo $title;?></h1></div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/users_group');?>" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">', '</div>'); ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?php 
$data = array(
'class' => 'col-sm-2'
);
echo form_label('User Group Name', 'name', $data)
;?>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<?php 
$data = array(
'id' => 'name', 
'name' => 'name', 
'class' => 'form-control', 
'value' => set_value('name')
);
echo form_input($data)
;?>
</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Controller Name</td>
        <td>Access</td>
        <td>Modify</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($controller_files) { ?>
<?php foreach ($controller_files as $controllers) { ?>
<tr>

<td>
<div class="clearfix">

<div class="pull-left">
<?php echo $controllers['name']; ?>
</div>

<div class="pull-right">

<?php if ($controllers['installed']) { ?>
<span class="label label-success">Installed</span>
<span class="label label-danger"><a style="color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $controllers['edit'];?>">Edit Individual Controller</a></span>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="label label-primary">Not Installed</span>
<?php } ?>

</div>

</div>

</td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>


</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
</div>
</div><!-- Panel End -->
<?php echo form_close();?>

</div><!-- # Page Inner End -->
</div><!-- # Page End -->

</div><!-- # Wrapper End -->
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');?>
```

Comment: The error says that the function `getId()` is returning an array and not string. But what you have done should return value of column `user_group_id`. Thats quite strange.
Can you try returning the whole row like this `return $query->row();` and using this `$this->getId($controller)->user_group_id` instead.

Comment: Still same error showing. When I click on button it shows correct id.

Comment: Can you explain the exact flow whats happening. Which button?

Comment: The Users_group_update shows a list of controllers that are installed on to database or are new,
when i click on edit button in the view it leads me to that controller and i can edit it. example link `http://localhost/project/admin /users_group_controller_update/127` In the $data['controller_files'][] I have edit with site_url. I need the last segment to pick up id, where $this->uri-segment(3) is name of usergroup and the get where controller. Bit strange why showing string error.

Comment: I guess the `id` is the 4th URI parameter. Try this `$this->uri->segment(4)`.

Comment: Tell me one thing, the error is occurs which coming on the edit page or after submitting the form on edit page? Also where it redirects after the form is submitted?

Comment: No luck there 4 uri does not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73363/discussion-between-parag-tyagi-and-mustang83).

Comment: For some reason I added my db function inside the in_array and it worked fine now no errors show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With in my files variable  I had to use the db function to get it to work. No errors show now all fixed.

```
<?php

class Users_group_update extends Admin_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user_group');
}

public function index() {

    $data['title'] = "Users Group Update";

    $controller_files = $this->getInstalled($this->uri->segment(3)); 

    $data['controller_files'] = array();

    $files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

    if ($files) {

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $controller =  basename(strtolower($file), '.php');

            $do_not_list = array(
                'customer_total',
                'dashboard',
                'footer',
                'header',
                'login',
                'logout',
                'menu',
                'online',
                'permission',
                'register',
                'user_total'
            ); 

            if (!in_array($controller, $do_not_list)) {

                $this->db->where('name', $this->uri->segment(3));
                $this->db->where('controller', $controller);
                $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');

                if ($query->num_rows()) {

                $row = $query->row();

                $data['controller_files'][] = array(
                    'name' => $controller,
                    'installed' => in_array($controller, $controller_files),
                    'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group_controller_update' .'/'. $row->user_group_id)
                );

                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('template/user/users_group_form_update', $data);
}

public function getInstalled($name) {
    $controller_data = array();

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group');
    $this->db->where('name', $name);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {
        $controller_data[] = $result['controller'];
    }

    return $controller_data;
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create database query in your controller and put all task into one method

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group_controller_update') .'/'. $this->getId($controller)
```

to

```
'edit' => site_url('admin/users_group_controller_update' .'/'. $this->getId($controller))
```

Comment: Had same issue, but then found only way could make it work was use the codeigniter db function inside the in_array as shown below in my answer and now works, no errors.